# Pdf split, merge, bookmark etc

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I want to implement a functionality in which an end user can view pdf on a web page, then split it and combine different pages such as page (8, 13, 16 and so on) in a new pdf and then download it .

Or assume a different scenario in which an administrator wants to show some content of its pdf books to its website visitors like we see in google books or in other Online book shops
so that we can see some content of books before purchasing it.

In simple words to start from (make something like look inside feature  of Amazon).

Tell me how can I do it with little efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're looking to create some sort of preview of the PDF pages then you'll have to first convert the pages to images. You can then show those images on the web page just like Amazon or Google.

Also, if you want to do it with little effort then you'll have to go for some component which can help you convert the PDF pages to images. However, in order to show those images, you can simply use HTML/JavaScript. Moreover, you can [convert the PDF pages to images](http://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Working+with+Images) using [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx).

Please note that I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.